# Application URL working inside VM but not outside the VM/Vnet

Tags: https, port, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, qliksense

I have installed an application(QLik Nprinting) in a new Azure virtual machine. The application has a web portal that can be launched using URL http://servername:4994/. I can access this web portal inside the VM and in other VM which is in same VNet. But I cannot access the URL outside the VM i.e.in my client machine(intranet) which is not in Azure cloud.

I have opened the port 4994 (for inbound as well as for outbound) in both network interface and subnet in the Azure portal for the VM. I have turned off the windows firewall inside the VM machine. 
When tried to telnet inside VM using "Telnet appVMservername 4994" - it is responding but when tried to perform outside the VM i.e. in my client machine I got the error - "could not open connection to the host, on port 4994: connect failed"

The error I get when I access the URL outside the VM/Vnet: The web page can't be displayed.
I expect the URL should launch my app web portal outside the VM too without any issues.
Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Comment: You need to use a direct public IP or FQDN, so that you can access your VM from the public internet.  The server name can only work in your vnet.

Comment: We are not using public IP as per client requirement, we only use private IP and access within the intranet(not internet). The private IP or FQDN link is working for the port 443 i.e I can access https://<IP or FQDN>/ (which drives to another web portal) but not the https://<IP or FQDN>:4994/ . Please suggest.

Comment: If you are accessing it from outside the Vnet, you would need to connect via the public IP address. If you don't want to use a Public IP, you need to setup a VPN connection to the Vnet so you can connect privately to that Vnet and the VM on the private IP address

Answer (score 1):

To access your link from corporate LAN using the private IP address of the VM hosting the application, you need to have VPN [S2S, or P2S] or express route setup. The VPN gateway must sit in the same VNet as your application server.

Comment: Thank you all for your time in addressing the issue. The issue was with my client port restriction from client machines. Once the respective port was requested to open from our client machines, we were able to access the URL. Posting this hoping this could help anyone facing a similar issue.